# OAuth2 and Google API: about access token expired time

Tags: google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I have a access token which I call it A, and a refresh token.
so when I use the refresh token to refresh A, get a new access token which I call it B.
I have some questions:
1.older access token (A) is valid ? can I use it to request GOOGLE api?
2.if A is valid, how long will A expired?
3.if A is valid, the refresh token can refresh access token unlimited?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh OAuth token A, you cannot refresh it again. You need to use token B for the next refresh. Once you refresh token A to get token B, stop using token A.

Comment: what's the OAuth token?sorry,I don't understangd what you mean.can you say again clear,thanks

Comment: An OAuth token is what you get when you authenticate with OAuth 2.0